# bash script: Execute the same command on a list of output?

Tags: bash

I create a bash script where I am executing this K8S command line:

```sh
kubectl get nodes -o yaml | grep -- "- address:"
```

The output looks like this:

```
- address: 10.200.116.180
- address: node-10-200-116-180
- address: 10.200.116.181
- address: node-10-200-116-181
- address: 10.200.116.182
```

I would like to loop the output list and make some test on every address ip for example: `ping 10.200.116.182`.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What did not work?

Comment: I tried to create a regular expression to extract  the IP in  a mapfile,  but it does not work,

Comment: @Dominique ‘_the pipe translates this into `grep "0" "127.0.0.1"`_’ No it doesn’t. That would tell `grep` to read a file named `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: I would like to ping on the output address not in the localhost, then  the output of the kubectl is  a list of my @Ip, not just one

Comment: @Biffen: you're completely right, but what does it translate it to, then?

Comment: I tried this also: echo foo= $(kubectl get nodes -o yaml | grep -- "- address:")
But it does not give me what I am looking for too

Comment: I think the best idea is to put a regular expression to extract the @ip, putting it in an array or list, then applying a loop for this list in order to execute the needed commands on these IP @, my problem is that I am new with bash,

Comment: @Dominique Why does it have to ’translate’ to anything? It’s one command writing to STDOUT that gets piped to another command reading from STDIN. And I don’t see what it has got to do with this question.

Comment: @user6594048 Not that I condone parsing YAML like that, but that sounds like a good idea. Alternatively you could skip the array: `<get just the address> | while read -r addr ; do ping "$addr" …`. Maybe throw a `sort -u` in there. Either way you could probably find all the help you need on the internet. [bashfaq](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/bashfaq) could be a good place to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By replacing `grep` with `sed` you can directly get the IP list; and for storing those IPs in a bash array, you can use `mapfile -t` with a *process substitution*:

```sh
mapfile -t ips < <( 
    kubectl get nodes -o yaml |
    sed -nE 's/^[[:space:]]*- address: ([0-9.]+)$/\1/p'
)
```

Now you just have to loop through the array with a `for` loop:

```
for ip in "${ips[@]}"
do
    ping -c 1 "$ip"
done
```

Comment: Temporarily storing the output in an array is a waste of memory if you just need to process them one at a time, though. Simply `kubectl | sed | xargs -n 1 ping -c 1`

Comment: That's right. I didn't post the `xargs` solution because OP said that `ping` was just an example. `xargs` might be harder to handle for more complex processing.

Answer (score 1):

You can pipe the output to `xargs` and  execute the command you wish.

Before you do that you should clean up the output.
in your example pipe your output to :

`sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*- address: \([^[:space:]]*\)[[:space:]]*$/\1/g'`

you should end up with :

`kubectl get nodes -o yaml | grep -- "- address:" |  sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*- address: \([^[:space:]]*\)[[:space:]]*$/\1/g'`

Output should be only the addresses, like:

```
10.200.116.180
node-10-200-116-180
10.200.116.181
node-10-200-116-181
10.200.116.182
```

Now it is time to use the cleaned output to execute the `ping`.
To pass the addresses to ping we will use `xargs`.
To do that we are going to pipe the cleaned output to:

`xargs -I {IP} ping -c 1 -w 5 {IP}`

**Final command :**

`kubectl get nodes -o yaml | grep -- "- address:" |  sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*- address: \([^[:space:]]*\)[[:space:]]*$/\1/g' | xargs -I {IP} ping -c 1 -w 5 {IP}`